# Scraping a phone number from a list of Contact information

Tags: python

To get/strip the text from the below html part, I have parsed the page and taken in to a variable.

From that variable, i have scoped down to these particular divs to another variable called items. Now to strip the text(phone number in this case), I have used the list comprehension with for loop like, phone = [item.find(class_='phone').get_text() for item in items]

```
<div class="description">
<div class="phone">
   <a href="tel:(000) 000 -0000" title="call (000) 000 -0000">
     (000) 000 -0000
     </a>
</div>
<div class="description">
<div class="phone">
   <a href="tel:(111) 111 -1111" title="call (111) 111 -1111">
     (111) 111 -1111
     </a>
</div>
```

So i'm getting the result what i expected. Just those phone numbers in the Result.
['(000) 000 -0000','(111) 111 -1111']

My Problem is, When there is no phone number in the page under any of the div. I get the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'"

I know why we are getting this error. When the result returns as none, It throws an error that it cannot find a get_text attribute for none. I have gone through other articles for this error in Stackoverflow but didn't want to use the try except method instead I want to finish this is in single line.

This is what i'm thinking to do,

Running the command, **phone = [item.find(class_='phone') for item in items]** will get me something like below.

```
[None, <div class="phone"> <a href="tel:(000) 000-0000" title="call (000) 000-0000">(000) 000-0000</a> </div>, <div class="phone"> <a href="tel:(111) 111-1111" title="call (111) 111-1111">(111) 111-1111</a> </div>
```

After this, can we do a combination of if else and for loop together in a single line to strip the phone numbers and print "None" as it is if the list element has "None" value.

Trying something like this, **phone = [item='None' if item=='None' else item.find(class_='phone').get_text() for item in items]** However, I'm not getting the results. Any help is appreciated.

Referred article, [One-line list comprehension: if-else variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321138/one-line-list-comprehension-if-else-variants) and [Python for and if on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580489/python-for-and-if-on-one-line/32580576)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are comparing `'None'` to the class `NoneType`. The two are not equal. To get the proper results you must do something like this:

```py
numbers = ['None' if item == None else item.find(class_='phone'.get_text()) for item in items]
```

Notice how I compared the item to `None` (a nonetype) instead of `'None'` (a string).

Comment: I'm sorry it returns the same error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'"